# Grails db-migration table already exists

Tags: grails, grails-plugin, grails-domain-class, liquibase

I'm using Grails 1.3.7 and the db-migration plug-in.

I have generated a chagelog.groovy-file containing my delta, I set theese properties:

```
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true
grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStartFileNames = ['changelog.groovy‘]
```

Now in my Datasource.groovy I have the the dbCreate to update.

I start my application and it tells me that the table I have in my delta is already created.

Any ideas on this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't need to set any `dbCreate` option in your `DataSource.groovy`.

The migration plugin manages all necessary operations if you specified your delta correctly.

Example part of your `DataSource.groovy`:

```
production {
   dataSource {
      dbCreate = ""
      url = "yourDBUrl"
      username = "yourUser"
      password = "yourPassword"
   }
}
```

Comment: You mean this should be enough: grails.plugin.databasemigration.updateOnStart = true

Comment: No - you have to edit your `DataSource.groovy` as seen above (I updated my answer)

Comment: You might also want to mark your existing database as already synchronized so it doesn't try to apply the changesets that are already there.

Comment: Is it safer to set `dbCreate = "validate"` to ensure that the application doesn't try to run against a DB with an incorrect schema?